# Parsing cell data with NOPI

Tags: parsing

My cell has data like
"Title=Happiness,ISBN=123,Author=John;Title=Miracle,ISBN=456,Author=Laura"

i.e. there are two records in same cell.
Is it possible to read this like following?

```
Book[0].title = "Happiness"
Book[1].title = "Miracle"
Book[0].ISBN = "123"
Book[1].ISBN = "456"
```

Number of records = count of ";" + 1

Thanks

Comment: Please add more tags to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing.

```
public class ParsedInfo
{
    public string one { get; set; }
    public string two { get; set; }
    public string three { get; set; }
}

 public List<ParsedInfo> GiveParsedInfo(string RawData)
    {
        string temp;
        List<ParsedInfo> list = new List<ParsedInfo>();

        temp = Data.ToString();
        if (temp.Contains(","))
        {
            // first break it into multiple records for temp
            String[] Multiple = temp.Split(Convert.ToChar(";"));
            try
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Multiple.Length; j++)
                {
                    string rowdata = Multiple[j];
                    String[] strCols = rowdata.Split(Convert.ToChar(","));
                    list.Add(new ParsedInfo()
                    {
                        one = strCols[0].Substring(3),
                        two = strCols[1].Substring(3),
                        three = strCols[2].Substring(3),
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Name, e.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```